# Why I can't perform this insert query if a specific field value is set to null?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem trying to implement a simple **insert** query that insert a new record into an Oracle database.

So my table have the following structure:

```
DESCRIBE FLUSSO_XMLSDI

Nome           Nullo    Tipo         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
NUMERO_FATTURA NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15) 
DATA_EMISSIONE          DATE         
XML                     CLOB         
PFK_PIVA                VARCHAR2(16) 
PDF                     VARCHAR2(1)
```

So as you can see the last field of this table is named **PDF** and it is **nullable** and it have 1 character as length (It is defined as **VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)** but I think that it means that it can contain only a character).

So my problem is that if I do:

```
INSERT INTO FLUSSO_XMLSDI (NUMERO_FATTURA, DATA_EMISSIONE, XML, PFK_PIVA, PDF) 
       VALUES (004600002149, date'2015-03-16', 'TEST' , 80003690668, 'S');
```

It works and the new record is correctly inserted into my **FLUSSO_XMLSDI** table.

But when I try to do (setting the **PDF** field to **null):

```
INSERT INTO FLUSSO_XMLSDI (NUMERO_FATTURA, DATA_EMISSIONE, XML, PFK_PIVA, PDF) 
       VALUES (004600002149, date'2015-03-16', 'TEST' , 80003690668, null);
```

I obtain the following error message:

```
Errore con inizio alla riga 1 nel comando:
INSERT INTO FLUSSO_XMLSDI (NUMERO_FATTURA, DATA_EMISSIONE, XML, PFK_PIVA, PDF) 
       VALUES (004600002149, date'2015-03-16', 'TEST' , 80003690668, null)
Report errori:
Errore SQL: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "EDIWEA.TRI_P_FLUSSO", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EDIWEA.TRI_P_FLUSSO'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Why I can't specify that the **PDF** field value as **null** also if it is nullable? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: There is a trigger on the table: EDIWEA.TRI_P_FLUSSO. What does it do?

Comment: In the trigger EDIWEA.TRI_P_FLUSSO there's probably some SELECT...INTO statement that does not give a result when the PDF field is NULL

Comment: While the table schema allows nulls, there appears to be a trigger that operates on the value in the column that expects a value.

Either the trigger needs to be rewritten to handle nulls or the table schema should be changed (if possible) to not allow them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error `no data found`

```
 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EDIWEA.TRI_P_FLUSSO'
```

might be caused from a `select * into variable from dual` and its returning empty values, the select should return records to b added to the variables, so you have either to adjust the select to return values or comment it, so the triggers works.

there are might another reasons for that error , we cannot help you unless you show us the trigger.